# C++ passing function in argument to another function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to pass function to a function, declaration looks like

```
double fun1(const double* ang, std::function<double(double)> f1)
```

In the `main()`, I am creating function pointer  and pointing it to another 
function as

```
std::function<double(double)> f2 = &fun5; //line1
```

and calling function `fun1` as

```
double x = fun1(&a,f2);
```

This works. But, if I call function as

```
double x = fun1(&a,&f2);
```

,it gives error as

> could not convert '& f2' from 'std::function*' to 'std::function

Creating reference works at `line1` but calling function with reference does not work. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: `&f2` give a **pointer** to `f2`

Comment: Can I accept pointer `f1` in `fun1()` definition? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `fun5` is a function
- `&fun5` is a pointer to a function of the type: `double (*)(double)`
- `f2` is a functor object specifically of the type: `function<double(double)>`
- `&f2` is the address of this functor object it has the type: `function<double(double)>*`

Because `fun1` expects a functor object passing it a pointer to the functor object is illegal. Think about this in terms of `int`s if that's simpler. If for example I have a function: `void foo(int arg)`, and I have an `int bar` I cannot do:

```
foo(&bar)
```

This whould simply be passing an `int*` as `arg`, which is obviously illegal. What would have to happen is:

```
foo(bar)
```

Similarly your function wants a functor object. You need to pass it the functor object not the pointer, so:

```
fun1(&a, f2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First lets understand whats the scenario , first you have created f2 which is &fun5 so basically you have created an alias of fun5 which is f2 ,now according to your function parameter the 2nd argument expects a function like f2 which you have passed in the first case but in the second case you need to have a special variable called pointer's to point to the reference/address you have passed so modify the second parameter to *something and your second case would work fine.